# Solution of ODE system is of class $C^k$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

In the proof of showing existence and uniqueness of integral
curves (Theorem 2.8.4) in *Differentiable Manifold* by *Lawrance Conlon*, it uses the folowing lemma(Lemma C.3.5):

(Notation: $X$ is a compact supported vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ of class $C^k$; $j\leq k$; $J_x\Phi(t,x)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $\Phi(t,x)$ over variable $x$.)

[image]

[image]

**My question is**, the proof of Lemma C.3.5 seems only prove that $J_x\Phi(t,x)$ is of class $C^{j-1}$ in $t$, why is it also true for $x$?

(the remark referenced in the proof of Lemma C.3.5 is the following)
[image]